# Remaining time until weekend is over

Tags: c#

I want to calculate how many seconds there are left until the weekend is over (say until Sunday 11.59PM). when the operation is called in the weekend it needs to return a TimeSpan. I need to do this on a weekly basis so i cant set a 'hard-coded' enddate like

```
new DateTime(2014, 04, 17, 23, 12, 33);
```

how do i set a correct enddate to calculate the remaining seconds from now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    //Your code goes here
    TimeSpan span = (Next(DateTime.Now, DayOfWeek.Sunday).Date + new TimeSpan(23, 59, 00)).Subtract(DateTime.Now);          
    Console.WriteLine(span.TotalSeconds);
}
public static DateTime Next(DateTime from, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
   int start = (int) from.DayOfWeek;
   int target = (int) dayOfWeek;
   if (target <= start) target += 7;
     return from.AddDays(target - start);
}
```

[Here is Demo](http://rextester.com/BOXC84147)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DayOfWeek` property to find the remaining number of days till the end of the week and create a new `DayTime` object by adding them to the `StartDate`.

```
DateTime endDate = startDate.Date.AddDays(7 - (int)startDate.DayOfWeek)
```